# A question about qqplot

Tags: qq-plot, extreme-value, heavy-tailed

This is my qq plot : 
[image]

Its concave-convex curve so it indicates light tails. But my mean excess plot :

[image]

is increases which means the tail of the distribution of my data is heavy-tailed.

I don't understand why. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have such huge white space around your plots? I can't read your axes

Comment: I used the mean excess function in R. in y-axis : The mean excess values and in x-axis : the threshold.

Comment: I have posted versions of your plots with the excess white space removed. You may still need to add additional information to make what you did sufficiently clear.

Comment: Someone can explain me why are the data points clustering in the mean excess plot and in the QQ-plot too ? thanks in advance

Comment: You did the same thing with the plot you replaced -- left it surrounded with a gigantic amount of white space. Please remove that so we can look at the plot

Comment: Your data clearly include a lot of tied values. No continuous distribution is going to look any good. Are the largest values censored/truncated?

Comment: No,the largest values are not censored or truncated

Comment: Why are they bounded? Why the big jump just before the upper limit? What values are we looking at there?

Comment: this data comes from claims reserving in third party liability. You think these values are truncated ?

Comment: Like from a policy limit, say, or (in some jurisdictions) a legal limit on third party payments, or from reinsurance (if the values recorded are the net liability of the original insurer), say? ... perhaps.

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry but I dont understand clearly

Comment: Those are examples of things that would give a hard cut off (either by truncation or winsorization) where otherwise the amount recorded may be larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can define the mean-excess function to be:

$$e_X(d) = \mathbb E(X - d | X > d )$$

If a distribution has a thin tail, I'd expect this function to get smaller and smaller if I keep increasing $d$. That's exactly what's happening with your function over the threshold $X = 2e+06$.

The ME plot is meant to be interpret after a particular threshold (because you're only interested in the tail of this distribution).

Comment: So should I use GPD or GEV distribution ? What about the QQplot? thanks in advance